# python -m SimpleHTTPServer no longer working

Tags: python

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 was working fine in order to render my web pages on localhost. When it quit, I used 7800, which also failed eventually, and now no numerical string works. For example, having launched the server using python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7600, I get the following when trying to render through the browser (any browser):

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 7600 ...
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 20:14:04] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 20:14:04] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 20:14:19] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2022 20:14:19] "GET /FrontandBackMatter/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I get this result having changed nothing in the files.

Comment: made sure you `cd` to the site directory first?